# Removing week days rows in R

Tags: r, date

I have data looks like :

[image]

`dput()` :

```
structure(list(time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L), .Label = c("2014-07-01 00:01:11", "2014-07-01 00:01:12", 
"2014-07-01 00:02:10", "2014-07-01 00:02:14", "2014-07-01 00:03:12", 
"2014-07-01 00:05:11", "2014-07-01 00:05:12", "2014-07-01 00:07:10", 
"2014-07-01 00:07:11", "2014-07-01 00:07:12", "2014-07-01 00:07:15", 
"2014-07-01 00:09:11", "2014-07-01 00:09:12", "2014-07-01 00:11:11", 
"2014-07-01 00:11:12", "2014-07-01 00:12:10", "2014-07-01 00:12:14", 
"2014-07-01 00:13:11", "2014-07-01 00:13:12", "2014-07-01 00:15:11", 
"2014-07-01 00:15:12", "2014-07-01 00:17:10", "2014-07-01 00:17:11", 
"2014-07-01 00:17:12", "2014-07-01 00:17:14", "2014-07-01 00:17:19", 
"2014-07-01 00:19:11", "2014-07-01 00:19:12", "2014-07-01 00:21:11", 
"2014-07-01 00:21:12"), class = "factor"), type = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("activity", "battery", "bluetooth", "location", 
"wifi"), class = "factor"), value1 = structure(c(10L, 10L, 6L, 
2L, 11L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 
1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 11L, 
12L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("", "35.1897751", "35.189777", 
"35.189782", "35.1897954", "discharging", "dlink", "iptime", 
"JIN iptime", "none", "PATECH-AP", "SHW-A300K(88**)"), class = "factor"), 
    value2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 11L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 11L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 12L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    5L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 11L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "00:26:5a:2f:29:82", "00:26:66:68:ae:18", "126.9063212", 
    "126.9063384", "126.9063733", "126.9063876", "64:e5:99:71:40:96", 
    "7c:3e:9d:19:33:b1", "7c:3e:9d:19:33:b5", "7c:3e:9d:19:33:b6", 
    "7c:3e:9d:19:33:b7"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("time", 
"type", "value1", "value2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50"))
```

If this example does not enough, you can download sample data through [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iuica2tba2uz8vq/sample.txt?dl=0)

My questions are :

1. I want to remove week days, it means saturday and sunday data, because
   I just want to use data from monday until friday.
2. I have one more question. I want to change the time only in hour
   format, the example is: If the minute is less than 30 so I want to
   change to previous time, and when minutes is more than 30 I want
   rounding to next time.  if time < 12:30, time result is 12:00 if
   time > 12:30, time result is 13:00.  Actually, I can use split and
   then using if condition, but is there any more simple and efficient
   way?

Comment: Your example data only has one day in it.  Please show a more representative example

Comment: Hai Richard, I've updated my question. my data, for the one day contain around more than 1K rows, so I put it in txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out weekends (Saturday and Sunday) like this:
(Assume your data.frame is called `x`)

```
x[!weekdays(as.Date(x$time)) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"),]
```

or (if you're not in an English locale)

```
x[!as.POSIXlt(x$time)$wday %in% c(0, 6),]
```

You can round to the nearest hour by converting to `POSIXct` and using `round`

```
round(as.POSIXct(x$time), units="hours")
```

Comment: Hai @Gsee Thank you for your answer, for the round it works well but for removing weekends, after I applied to my data, It just remove sunday.

Comment: @user46543 I tried it on your data, and it worked for me.  Can you add the output of `sessionInfo()` to your Question?

Comment: I see, I can solve my problem, thank you Gsee. The problem is, I run `x[!weekdays(as.Date(x$time)) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"),]` first instead of round command. So the time 7/4/2014 23:45 will be converted to 7/5/2014 00:00. After I run round command first and then removing week days, It works well. :)